# How to recognize the speech text which is out of choices in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I Have below code to recognize the speech text from my choices.

```
Public speechRecognitionEngine As SpeechRecognitionEngine

Private Sub SpeechRecog()
    Try
        speechRecognitionEngine = New SpeechRecognitionEngine(SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers()(0))
        AddHandler speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf engine_SpeechRecognized
        Dim texts As Choices = New Choices()
        texts.Add("HOW")
        texts.Add("ARE")
        texts.Add("YOU")
        Dim wordsList As Grammar = New Grammar(New GrammarBuilder(texts))
        speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(wordsList)
        speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
        speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Voice recognition failed")
    End Try
End Sub

Public reader As System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer

Public Sub engine_SpeechRecognized(sender As Object, e As SpeechRecognizedEventArgs)
   If e.Result.Confidence > 0.9 Then
      usrText.Text = e.Result.Text
   Else
      reader = New Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
      reader.SpeakAsync("Please speak clear and louder")
   End If
End Sub
```

If I am speaking anything from my choices then it is working.
If confidence is more than .9 then printing else saying that ***"Please speak clearly and louder"***

But if I am speaking anything other than my choices then it is not doing anything.

Is there any way that if somebody saying any text out of choices then I can say that ***INVALID TEXT***

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Just a helpful tip .. Don't include tags that dont relate directly to your question. As it doesnt have anything to do with C# the tag shouldn't be there. I understand that you want to reach the widest possible audience, but C# and VB.Net are different enough that often, people in "the other camp" won't be able to answer, and they want to filter out questions from the other language. We like to be able to focus on what we know :-)

Comment: sometimes back, I felt like not getting enough help when I added just VB.Net. But after adding C#, I got quick suggestions. so that why I added both the tags here. but thanks for your helpful tip...

Answer (score 2):

You should add another handler: [RecognizeCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.recognizecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Using the handler for the RecognizeCompleted event, you can access the
>   RecognitionResult in the RecognizeCompletedEventArgs object. If
>   recognition was not successful, RecognitionResult will be null. To
>   determine whether a timeout or an interruption in audio input caused
>   recognition to fail, you can access the properties for
>   InitialSilenceTimeout, BabbleTimeout, or InputStreamEnded.

Comment: This is why I always stress for people to read the documentation. When people don't read it, they miss documented important things that could have saved them from being stuck in the first place. When you just blindly follow someone else's online example demonstration code/tutorial and don't think for yourself, you don't help yourself and miss important things. For the record, this comment isn't about OP, but its in general.